# WSO2 Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding chunked

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, content-length, transfer-encoding

We need to send the content length in order to implements a progress bar for webservices using WSO2 Api manager. WSO2 API manager delete the content-length and by default send the response with Transfer-Encoding :chunked.

We try without any succes the following lines:

```
<property name="FORCE_HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" value="true" scope="axis2"/>

<property name="COPY_CONTENT_LENGTH_FROM_INCOMING" value="true" scope="axis2"/> 

<property name=”DISABLE_CHUNKING” value=”true” scope=”axis2″/>
```

Also the following configuration into **/repository/conf/passthru-http.properties**, but we have a problem with the WS sending the 204 response code (No content) when the content-length is sended :

```
http.headers.preserve=Content-Length
```

We think that some of this configuration must to be used, but were to put it in order to be take in count for the existing APIs?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

After you're done, try restarting the server
I did it and it successes

Answer (score 0):

Having bellow properties will make chunking disabled.

```
<property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2" />
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
```

Comment: I have been already tryed to add these properties but doesn't work for me.